# Django: pass data from CBV form view to form CBV

Tags: django

I have `Form` with a `ModelChoiceField`, which is being used as the `form_class` in a `FormView`.

The choice field has to be populated with information bound to the `request` object.

Let's summarize:

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    # I need to pass `request.user` and a value 
    # derived from `request.GET['pk']` to the form
    form_class = MyForm

class MyForm(Form):
    choices = ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyChoice.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, user, number, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choices'] = MyChoice.objects(number=number, owner=user)
```

What would I need to do to pass that data to the form when its instance is created?

I tried overriding `get_form` but I am unsure this is the proper way of doing this:

```
 def get_form(self, form_class):
        user = self.request.user
        number = SomeModel.objects.get(self.GET['pk']).number
        return form_class(user, number, **self.get_form_kwargs())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overriding `get_form` would work, but a better approach would be to override [`get_form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs), so that you don't have to duplicate code from the `get_form` method.

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(MyFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        kwargs['number'] = SomeModel.objects.get(self.GET['pk']).number
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Then I would have to pop `'user'` and `'number'` from kwargs rathen than having them as arguments in the form constructor right?

Comment: No, that's not correct. Since you have `def __init__(self, user, number, *args, **kwargs)`, there is no need to pop `user` and `number` from kwargs.

Comment: Oh right, since I explicitly declare those arguments I don't need to inspect `kwargs` at all in the form constructor. What would I need to change to include that data in the `kwargs` rather than named arguments?

Comment: If you change the method signature to `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` then the `user` and `number` will be in `kwargs` inside the `__init__` method. In this case, you have to pop them, otherwise you'll get an error when you call `super`.