# Use FormMixin/FormView along with dynamically created forms

Tags: python, django, forms, mixins

While playing with `Forms` dynamically created (let's say, in order to have a multiple choice field filled up at runtime), is there a clean and programmatic way to use such `Form` along with `FormView` class?

```
class MultipleChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, options, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MultipleChoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['calendars'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                                      widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                      choices=[(o['id'], o['summary']) for o in options],
                                      required=True)
```

As per now I managed to overload the `get_form()` method of my `FormView`:

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    """
    Returns an instance of the form to be used in this view.
    """
    if form_class is None:
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
    return form_class(self.options, **self.get_form_kwargs())
```

But I feel it's a bit hacky... Probably this question has already been asked, but is it a cleaner and easier solution to this basic scenario?

Comment: It's slightly cleaner to override `get_form_kwargs` instead. See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237742/django-pass-data-from-cbv-form-view-to-form-cbv/43237839) from last week.

Comment: @Alasdair correct, but I don't think it will save me from the burden of rewriting big part of the Mixin logic (validation, binding....) :/

Comment: Why do you think your code breaks validation? You don't have to rewrite the mixin logic - overriding `get_form_kwargs` lets you ad an extra kwargs `options` when instantiating the form. The rest of the form binding/validation code should work unchanged.

Comment: @Alasdair the POST fails with 'select a valid choice' and the form is re-rendered without any choice: it seems it doesn't retain the options I have created at runtime...

Comment: You'll need to include some more info about how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually it's quite logic, as the 'options' are volatile and the second time I call 'get_form_kwargs()' the form will be created with empty options. I should store and retrieve these options in the context maybe?

Comment: Yes, you need to ensure that `options` is the same for GET and POST requests to the view. If you include the options in the URL (e.g. in the querystring) or in `request.POST` (e.g. as a hidden field), then be aware that the user could tamper with them.

Comment: @Alasdair, the error I just fixed a few minutes ago. GET or POST is not an option, as it would be a big security hole (letting client choose what to validate or not of my Form), better to recreate them on the fly or to put them in a session. Anyway I will remove the part about breaking the mixin logic, at least it seems to work like this. Thanks a lot.